# woocommerce composite products - surcharge some item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for answers for many many days and hours... And for the moment, in Woothemes I have no feedback to my question.

I begin with WordPress and Woocommerce.

The plugin Composite products is absolutely what I needed, except for one thing :

My composite products have a fixed price. My components are like a restaurant's menu (it's for a fast-food) that people can custom.

But my problem is that for a few products, i have to surcharge. I have to add 2 or 3 euros to my Composite product's price, and when the product with surcharge is selected, price has to be shown in this product page, and of course has to be calculated in my cart.

I think there is an issue with wordpress filters and actions, but it's not yet completely clear in my brain !!!

I tried to write a PHP code for the cart, it works
but I think that ergonomically it's not a good solution, people has to see directly the new price in product page when he makes his selection.

Comment: Using per item pricing won't work? I'd wager that there are enough hooks and filters to get this done, but it would be complicated.

Comment: No, it doesn't make what I want. My composite products must have fixed price. It's just where some products are chosen that I have to surcharge. Example : the customer chooses an orange juice, price of CP stays the same, but if he chooses the Heineken, he will have to pay 1€ more.
Some products like drinks can be also ordered individually.

In the plugin's doc there's many hooks but no examples, I'm lost with plugin's code, if I could get components, sale price when it is sold individually, get and add the new price in CP, I could write a home-made function.

Comment: I knew that's what you wanted. Per item pricing was kind of a "shot in the dark" since what you are describing is more than I can get in to on SO.